# google play service mainactivity

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I've implemented the Google Play Services demo code found at this url:

https://github.com/kpbird/google-play-service/blob/master/src/com/kpbird/googleplayservice/MainActivity.java

And everything works. However if the function getAccountNames() is called within onCreate, the application momentarialy flashes before loading the set content view. It's like there are two activity views are being initiatied.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAccount);
    txtToken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToken);
    getAccountNames();
}
```

Why would placing `getAccountNames()` in the `onCreate` create this visual effect when the application launches.

Comment: If you look at the source, getAccountNames does a newChooseAccountIntent, which starts some other Activity. that is why you get the flashing between views

Comment: From the Android Documentation: As a special case, if you call startActivityForResult() with a requestCode >= 0 during the initial onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)/onResume() of your activity, then your window will not be displayed until a result is returned back from the started activity. This is to avoid visible flickering when redirecting to another activity. 

Seems like I get this visible flickering they say should be avoided.

Comment: Yeah could be device dependant

Comment: or you can just call getAccountNames before setContentView